# How to pass values to mySQL nested subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a complicated query that boils down to this:

```
UPDATE usertable
SET userstatus =
    (SELECT numposts*5 as status FROM
        (SELECT count(*) as numposts FROM poststable WHERE poststable.userid = usertable.userid) as table2
    )
WHERE usertable.userid > 0
```

It's a query that updates every user record and sets the user's status to some calculated value based on the number of rows in a child table.

The problem is that usertable.userid does not make it down to the second level subquery.

The query works when presented like this, with only one level down:

```
UPDATE usertable
SET userstatus =
    (SELECT count(*) as numposts FROM poststable WHERE poststable.userid = usertable.userid)
WHERE usertable.userid > 0
```

The problem is that the calculation query in the real situation is very complicated.

The question is: is there a way I can get a 2nd level subquery to recognize a value from the top level query? In this example, is there a way to get usertable.userid recognized 2 levels down?

Thanks!
-Nico

Comment: looks like a bug, anyway why you cannot use `UPDATE usertable
SET userstatus = 5*
    (SELECT count(*) as numposts FROM poststable WHERE poststable.userid = usertable.userid)
WHERE usertable.userid > 0` ?

Comment: You can in this simplified example, but the real situation is far more complicated. I think I can work the real one down to one level, but it gets really awful that way. I was hoping for a better way.

Comment: In Oracle you would do this by writing a procedure/function that takes in the user id as a param returns the status -- in Oracle that will be very efficient.  In MySQL I am not sure on performance.  Have you explored writing a MySQL function for this?

Comment: hmm, it looks like mySQL only allows us to correlate subqueries to one level deep :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435644/mysql-scoping-problem-with-correlated-subqueries

Comment: Darn, it turns out I'm not Super enough to create functions, or that would have been a nice and clean solution. We are using a hosted database so I doubt I can get Super status. It works for one row in a stored procedure setting, so I'll keep trying that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a correlated subquery row by row, I would generate a derived table as a one-time subquery for all userid's, then join that to the table you want to update. MySQL supports multi-table update syntax:

```
UPDATE usertable AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS numposts
    FROM poststable
    GROUP BY userid
    ORDER BY NULL
) AS t USING (userid)
SET u.userstatus = 5 * COALESCE(t.numposts, 0)
WHERE u.userid > 0
```

I know you said your real query is more complex, but the same principle may solve it.