# Table alias is unknown in nested subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works just fine. I am using a value from the outer select to filter inside the inner select.

```
SELECT
    bk.ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM guests WHERE BookingID = bk.ID) as count
FROM
    bookings bk;
```

However, the following select will not work:

```
SELECT
    bk.ID,
    (SELECT SUM(count) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM guests WHERE BookingID = bk.ID GROUP BY RoomID) sub) as sumcount
FROM
    bookings bk;
```

The error message is: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bk.ID' in 'where clause'`

Why is my alias `bk` known in the subselect, but not in the subselect of the subselect?

For the record, I am using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: What's the logic of the second query - you want to produce separate counts for each `RoomID` but then throw away any room information and just add them together? Could you add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: This is a VERY reduced and simplified example, part of a very large and very complex data scheme. Put simply, the innermost select is supposed to count occurrences by day, and the sum-select is supposed to sum them up for each month. Yes, this does sound superfluous, but sadly, it is not. It has to be done like that. However, I am not looking for a different way to do it, I am wondering why the inner select suddenly does not recognize the alias from the outer select anymore.

Comment: I suspect its an issue with it being used within a subselect defined in a `FROM` clause, as opposed to your original where you reference it in the `WHERE` clause. But not 100% sure.

Comment: Standard SQL simply doesn't allow correlation into a Derived Table. You must rewrite it using a Left Join to a Derived Table

Comment: @dnoeth If this is "simply not allowed", why does the first select work?

Comment: In the 1st select you got a Correlated Scalar Subquery, but in the 2nd select there's s Derived Table `FROM (this is a Derived Table) sub` within the Scalar Subquery.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "scoping".  I know that Oracle (for instance) only looks out one level for resolving table aliases.  SQL Server is also consistent:  it looks out more than one level.

Based on this example, MySQL clearly limits the scope of the identifier `bk` to the immediate subquery.  There is a small hint in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/correlated-subqueries.html) (emphasis mine):

> A correlated subquery is a subquery that contains a reference to a
>   table that also appears in **the** outer query.

However, I have not found any other specific reference to the scoping rules in the documentation.  There are other answers ([here](http://www.codedisqus.com/0SzqeVWjXq/mysql-scoping-problem-with-correlated-subqueries.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435644/mysql-scoping-problem-with-correlated-subqueries)) that specify that the scope of a table alias is limited to one level of subquery.

You already know how to fix the problem (your two queries should produce identical results).  Re-arranging the query to have joins and aggregations can also resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Correlated Scalar Subqueries in the SELECT list can usually be rewritten to a LEFT JOIN on a Derived Table (and in many cases they might perform better then):

```
SELECT
    bk.ID,
    dt.sumcount
FROM
    bookings bk
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT BookingID,SUM(COUNT) AS sumcount
  FROM
   (
     SELECT BookingID, RoomId, COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
     FROM guests 
     GROUP BY BookingID, RoomID
    ) sub
  ) AS dt
ON bk.BookingID = dt.BookingID
```