# what is wrong with this sql query?ERROR 1054 (42S22)

Tags: mysql, sql

**ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'm.match_id' in 'where clause'**

`(select m.match_id,m.team1,m.team2,m.team1_score from match_results as m
where
m.team1_score=(
select max(score) from (
select p.team1_score as score from match_results p where p.match_id=m.match_id
UNION 
select q.team2_score as score from match_results q where q.match_id=m.match_id
) as T
))
UNION
(select m1.match_id,m1.team1,m1.team2,m1.team2_score from match_results m1
where
m1.team2_score=(
select max(score) from (
select team1_score as score from match_results where match_id=m1.match_id
UNION 
select team2_score as score from match_results where match_id=m1.match_id
)as T
));`

**Schema: match_results(match_id,team1,team2,team1_score,team2_score)**
team1 and team2 are varchar()
team1_score and team2_score are integers.
I am trying to fetch team(team1 or team2) with maximum score(team1_score or team2_score))

Comment: You'll need to post the schema and the error message or what you need it to do.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You don't have equal number of columns selected in both the queries of UNION. The first query doesn't have  `match_id` in select. You need to add `m.match_id` at the start of the first select query

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : updated query, now it has same number of columns also of same data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified your query

```
select m.team1,m.team2,m.team1_score 
   from match_results as m,
        match_results as p
  where m.team1_score= greatest (p.team1_score, p.team2_score)
    AND m.match_id = p.match_id

UNION

select m.team1,m.team2,m.team2_score 
   from match_results as m,
        match_results as p
  where m.team2_score= greatest (p.team1_score, p.team2_score)
    AND m.match_id = p.match_id
```

Will you have same match_id repeated more than one time? (logically No!) If so use the above query else you use even simple

This query will give the score of team1 if team1's score is greatest. It will give team2's score, if team2 scored higher than team1

```
 select m.team1, m.team2, greatest (m.team1_score, m.team2_score)
       from match_results as m
```

Comment: Thanks a ton....greatest() resolved everything, but i am still wondering what could be wrong in query that i posted in question, even after removing aliases T or giving different alias names , i am getting the same error, could you please comment on this?

Comment: Even am wondering about the error. Try running query with just one query in where clause.. I mean where m.team1_score = select max(p.team1_score) as score from match_results p where p.match_id=m.match_id.. see if there is error still

Comment: but that would not satisfy what i want to achieve, may be the reason is for a correlated query the correlation should be specified in immediate inner query

Comment: Yes.. am asking you to debug that way

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435644/mysql-scoping-problem-with-correlated-subqueries. Looks like you cannot refer the table in from clause after nesting it in subquery

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 1054 (42S22)

This error means you have the wrong name for one of your fields.
Either you aliased it and use the wrong alias, or simply the wrong field name.
Also, why do you have two `AS t` in your query?